# NodeMCU module enduser_setup: Program does not compile

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I built NodeMCU firmware with module enduser_setup, but when using it in Arduino IDE the compilation stops with this error:

> enter code here test_:35: error: 'enduser_setup' was not declared in this scope`

Do I need to include something else?

Comment: Is there any more info you need before you could accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding. There are two choices but you mixed and matched them.

If you want to program the Arduino way then you don't need the NodeMCU firmware. You have to be prepared to compile and upload the entire binary to the device every time you change a single bit in your program.

If you want to program in [Lua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)), a scripting language not too different from JavaScript, then you need to [flash the NodeMCU firmware](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/flash/) first. After that you simply [upload your Lua script(s)](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/upload/) and (re)start the execution or invoke the new functions you just uploaded. You won't need the Arduino IDE at all for this.

Disclaimer: I'm a member of the NodeMCU firmware team and thus I can't deny being slightly biased as to which approach I prefer.

Comment: thanks a lot. do you know if there is a similar approach using Arduino IDE like module enduser setup?